# Setup Installer creation using Visual Studio 2010 for application developed in VS Express 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have developed a **winform** application using **VS Express 2015.**Now I want to create a '**Setup Installer**' to deploy my application on client machines. Maybe I am asking a silly/stupid question, but still I want to know if it's possible to create the **Setup Installer** using **Visual Studio 2010**. I haven't tried it because of currently limited HD Space in my laptop.

Comment: did you google first before you posted your question?

Comment: yes sure i googled but didn't find any suitable answer.

Comment: i am asking a serious question here . i really need to create the setup installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes it is possible. I think this is the documentation you are looking for:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/19x10e5c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766795.aspx

Comment: thanks a lot for understanding my problem and offering me the urls unlike the others. In my country internet speed is quite low hence not able to google fast and search possible solutions.I really really appreciate your help. Once again thanks a lot @ skyler :)

Comment: _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_.  Consider editing your answer to contain a summary of the article pointed to by the link.

Comment: @Micky thanks for commenting so that I know why I am being down voted. Since the question was asking if it is possible and the asker was having trouble finding the docs, I will leave it as is for now.